# How to cast a box shadow only on certain elements

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to cast a box-shadow from a div, but to not allow the shadow to cast ONTO certain other divs?

Thought of another way: is it possible to exclude a certain div from having shadows drawn ON it?

For a concrete example: http://jsfiddle.net/Cd6fE/

How can I make the shadow cast by `.p1` NOT be cast on `.noShadowsOnMePlease` but continue to cast it's shadow on the OTHER divs?

I'm completely open to using js/jquery if that is the only solution, but who doesn't want to do this with pure css, amiright?

**Solution:** Basically, no, but you can fake it if the shadow is static.
Also, css masking would probably work, if you're on the cutting edge.  Browser support would likely be spotty as of Jan 2014.  Best solutions without css masking: http://jsfiddle.net/zExS9/ - uses `:before` selector to create invisble shadow pieces, then hides overflow.

Really makes you long for an `accepts-shadows: false;` attribute, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is: **no, you can't**.

The best I could do: http://jsfiddle.net/Cd6fE/5/

You can put your `.p1` a transparent background : it will **draw a transparent shape on the shadow**. It's all you can do I think.

Then I hide the last shadow parts with blue pseudo elements.

Comment: Read again the question and check the example.

Comment: This is getting closer!  I added a second div which could hold the content, thus making `.p1` essentially just a fake element only there to cast the shadow, and the result is convincing: http://jsfiddle.net/Cd6fE/9/

Comment: Yeah, it's faking nice :), but it will work only on plain color elements. I hope you don't use background images ;)

Comment: Exactly, and therein lies the problem.  I'm looking to see if I can use jquery to "snip" the background image using the shape as a mask, and then apply the snip to the cover-ups, but that would not allow for animation of the shadow, which I need, so it may not be possible for my purposes afterall.

Comment: I guess you can try CSS masks to do it. But it's highly experimental : http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that, too, because if I understand css masks correctly, it would even allow for animating the shadow over the mask.  Something to look into once I've met my deadline and I can toy with the site once my client is happy =P.  Would be a nice free upgrade to offer!

Answer (score 1):

This solution can apply on your work, try with some pseudo-selector like `:after` like this:

```
.p2:before, .p3:before, .p4:before {
  display:block;
  content:" ";
  position:absolute;
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px#000;
  background:black;
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zExS9/)**

Comment: That's a nice effect, and a good way to fake it over a background image, but still doesn't solve the animation problem.  I'll add your fiddle to the solutions, though, because it is great for people looking for static shadows.

Comment: If p1 slides up and to the right by 5 pixels when hovered, for example, the shadows can't move with the div and fade in simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You could use z-index to position the elements over the element that is casting a shadow. That way the shadow will be underneath the element, and not visible.

[Here is an Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cd6fE/3/)

Only the third box `.p3` has a shadow on it.

**Edit** -- Instead you could use the box shadow with inset and cast shadows inside of the divs.. [Here is another fiddle of that example](http://jsfiddle.net/Cd6fE/7/), you will need to adjust the position of the shadows, I just did this quick to show you.

You will want to add vendor prefixes to the box-shadow as well, -moz-, -webkit-, -o-

Comment: Are you suggesting that the container div have a higher z-index than the object casting the shadow?  Wouldn't that cover the whole casting div?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realize you were trying to remove the shadow from the containing div.

Comment: Your fiddle I understand, but can you manage to get the shadow to cast on all the `p's` without it casting on the background div (`.noShadowsOnMePlease`)?

Comment: It would be somewhat effective, but this obviously is a simplified example.  In reality the shadows are fairly complicated, and trying to use inset on the shadow-receiving elements would be tedious if not impossible.

Comment: On another note, shadows are out of style. It's all about flat design

Comment: Truth.  This was going to be a slick little effect, subtle and classy, but sadly it seems it is not to be.

Answer (score 0):

There's ways to fake it, but actually stopping it from rendering I think you are SOL

The easiest way is turn the shadow blue, then it looks like its not rendering on the background

Comment: Yes, but naturally in my production environment the background is an image, not a solid color =P.  I'm open to faking it, as long as it sells the effect, but I am not sure it is possible.